# Force ASP.NET MVC3 handler to ignore .cshtml and .vbhtml URLs and just pass them through

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing, nancy

It seems that MVC3 has a priority handler for .cshtml and .vbhtml file extensions and tries to locate them in the default folder.

When requesting these URLs:

- domain.com/test.cshtml
- domain.com/test.vbhtml

MVC always looks for these specific static files in a default folder.

Regardless of the extension or the route, I want it to completely ignore the .cshtml & .vbhtml handling and just pass the full URL through like all other URLs so I can take care of the routing on my own (with Nancy).

Running MVC3+Nancy+Razor on IIS 7.5 on an Azure instance.

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
   <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

to your web.config. Starting with the next version of Nancy (0.10), the Razor engine will automatically add this to the web.config

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. It seems this line only blocks the .cshtml and .vbhtml files in /Views, then IIS returns code status 404. I need to let the URLs pass through like valid ones to Nancy and route them elsewhere.

Comment: Odd.. we had a reported issue where the default handler would intercept request to routes that shared the same name as views.. we were advice by ppl on the MVC team to use this and it solved it for that particular case